# How to conditional subset a list in R based on range in another column

Tags: r, purrr

I have imported more than 100 equal .xls files with 10 sheets each into a list in R. I am now trying to get the information out that I need. The data in the files are highly unstructured.

I have created some toy data to show what I want.

```
# create my_list

list1 <- list(data.frame(cross = c("NA","NA","o","o","o","x","o","NA","NA"),
                         color = c("NA","NA","grey","black","white","yellow","blue","NA","NA"),
                         temperature = c("NA","NA","3","5","2","7","4","NA","NA")))

list2 <- list(data.frame(cross = c("NA","NA","o","x","o","o","o","NA","NA"),
                         color = c("NA","NA","grey","black","white","yellow","blue","NA","NA"),
                         temperature = c("NA","NA","8","6","1","6","9","NA","NA")))

my_list <- list(list1,list2)
```

I can easily select one value from my_list with purrr:map. The below code gives me a vector of e.g. the last given temperature in all the imported files:

```
# subset a single value from the list
my_list %>% map_chr(c(1,3,7))
[1] "4" "9"
```

The vector then has the same lenght as the number of files I have imported.

The important thing to notice here, is that the data are messy, there are many things in each column, due to the nature of the original .xls files. Thats why I select a single cell to extract from.

My question is: How do I select the color that have a "x" in the "cross" column, based on position 3 to 7?

As before, I need a vector of the color names, so output has to be:

"yellow","black" (if we look at the above toy data) and "NA" if no cross at all.

And remember, there are many strange things in each column, so I need to specify the range to look at in the "cross" column. In wording it could be:

"extract the name of the color, from the color column, thats has "x" next to it, in cross column, position 3 to 7. Since the "x" is always next to the colorname, I guess the range could be specified in either of the two columns (cross or color).

Hope for a purrr solution, but everything is thankfully accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, then this should do it:

```
map(my_list, function(tbl){
  out_tbl <- tbl[[1]][3:7,] %>%
    dplyr::filter(cross == "x")
  if(nrow(out_tbl) == 0) return(NA)
  as.character(out_tbl$color)
})
```

Comment: If you want to convert the above to a vector, then just apply unlist() afterwards. I'm not sure whether you just meant have the output from each element of my_list be a character vector.