# How to conditional subset a list in R based on range in another row

Tags: r, purrr

This question relates somehow to another question I asked 14 days ago.

[How to conditional subset a list in R based on range in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66547395/how-to-conditional-subset-a-list-in-r-based-on-range-in-another-column)

The difference here, is that I need to subset rows, instead of columns, and I cannot make that work.

I have imported more than 100 equal .xls files with 10 sheets each into a list in R. I am now trying to get the information out that I need. The data in the files are highly unstructured.

I have created some toy data to show what I want.

```
list3 <- list(data.frame(depth = c(NA,NA,NA,1,2,3,4,5),
                         col1 = c(NA,NA,"black",NA,"x",NA,NA,NA),
                         col2 = c(NA,NA,"blue",NA,NA,"x",NA,NA),
                         col3 = c(NA,NA,"white","x",NA,NA,NA,NA),
                         col4 = c(NA,NA,"grey",NA,NA,NA,"x",NA),
                         col5 = c(NA,NA,"yellow",NA,NA,NA,NA,"x")))

list4 <- list(data.frame(depth = c(NA,NA,NA,1,2,3,4,5),
                         col1 = c(NA,NA,"black",NA,NA,"x",NA,NA),
                         col2 = c(NA,NA,"blue",NA,NA,NA,"x",NA),
                         col3 = c(NA,NA,"white","x",NA,NA,NA,NA),
                         col4 = c(NA,NA,"grey",NA,"x",NA,NA,NA),
                         col5 = c(NA,NA,"yellow",NA,NA,NA,NA,"x")))

list5 <- list(data.frame(depth = c(NA,NA,NA,1,2,3,4,5),
                         col1 = c(NA,NA,"black",NA,"x","x",NA,NA),
                         col2 = c(NA,NA,"blue",NA,NA,NA,"x",NA),
                         col3 = c(NA,NA,"white","x",NA,NA,NA,NA),
                         col4 = c(NA,NA,"grey",NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                         col5 = c(NA,NA,"yellow",NA,NA,NA,NA,"x")))

my_list <- list(list3,list4,list5)

desired_result <- data.frame(depth = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
                             color = c("white","black","blue","grey","yellow",
                                       "white","grey","black","blue","yellow",
                                       "white","black","black","blue","yellow"))
```

As I mentioned in my previous question, the data are highly unstructered and I therefore need a solution based on subsetting a range.

I need to iterate over my list. I have done that with purrr:map with success so far. But this one I cant seem to figure out.

I need to link the color found on each depth in all my files. The result dont need to be in a dataframe, a vector for each depth is fine.

I hope for a purrr solution, but everything is thankfully accepted.

Comment: Check revised answer.  This takes care of your additional requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Additional requirement given in comments**

Your `my_list` actually has no names!  so try this syntax

```
library(janitor)
imap_dfr(my_list, ~(.x[[1]] %>% mutate(across(starts_with("col"), ~ifelse(. == "x", depth, .))) %>%
                                                           select(-depth) %>% row_to_names(3) %>% ungroup() %>%
                                                           pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "color", values_to = "depth", values_drop_na = T) %>%
                                                           mutate(list_name = .y)))

# A tibble: 15 x 3
   color  depth list_name
   <chr>  <chr>     <int>
 1 white  1             1
 2 black  2             1
 3 blue   3             1
 4 grey   4             1
 5 yellow 5             1
 6 white  1             2
 7 grey   2             2
 8 black  3             2
 9 blue   4             2
10 yellow 5             2
11 white  1             3
12 black  2             3
13 black  3             3
14 blue   4             3
15 yellow 5             3
```

If list contain names, the output will have names else index numbers of list.  Use of `imap_dfr` is recommended.  Assumption lied is here that third column contains color names.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But your output does not fit the desired output. E.g. in list1, the first depth (depth 1) is "white" not "black" as in your output.

Comment: I still dont think it is spot on. In my sample data, I have 4 depths with the color "black", in your output, there are only 3 depths with the color "black".

Comment: It looks like this is what I want. But I found out that I have some NA's in my depth column. The NA's are in [11:20,1] (column 1 row 11-20) and I need to replace them with c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) in all files in my list before I can proceed. I will return, thanks.

Comment: It is not really a part of my question. I just need to update my real data by replacing some NA's, before I can accept your answer. I need to see your code running on my real data.

Comment: It works perfectly - thanks a lot! I have accepted your answer. Do you have a quick tune, so I can see which list the data came from?

Comment: Yes, one variable with the list name, so I can go back an check my original files, if there is a typing mistake or so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

my_fun <-function(x){
  depth <- x %>% summarise(across(.cols = starts_with("col"),.fns=~depth[which(.=="x")])) %>%
    as.numeric()
  color <- select(x,starts_with("col"))[3,] %>% as.character(.)
  data.frame(depth,color) %>% arrange(depth)
}

map(my_list,function(l)do.call("rbind",map(l,my_fun))) %>% do.call("rbind",.)
```

Output:

```
#    depth  color
# 1      1  white
# 2      2  black
# 3      3   blue
# 4      4   grey
# 5      5 yellow
# 6      1  white
# 7      2   grey
# 8      3  black
# 9      4   blue
# 10     5 yellow
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will look into it and return. A short question: is there a way to replace the "starts_with" to specify which columns to look at by position? In the above example data, position 2:6.

Comment: Of course. You can replace `starts_with("col")` by `name_first_col:name_last_col`, in your case `col1:col5`.

Comment: I am sorry for giving some bad example data. I have updated the above example with another list, list5. The problem is that each depth can have the same color. In list5 there are two depths given the "black" color. I like your code an I can make it work on my real data, except if there are two  (or more) depths with the same color. Hope you have time to look into it - thanks.